# Flask app hosted by CherryPy: OPTIONS returns 404

Tags: flask, cherrypy, flask-restful, traefik, flask-cors

I have a restful API created using Flask and Flask-Restful. Everything works fine using the development server. All routes are in a Blueprint, though the particular route we're dealing with here is not a Flask-Restful one. It's just a normal Flask route.

I am also using Flask-CORS.

To deploy, everything is dockerized and I'm using CherryPy as the WSGI host. So a CherryPy app hosts the Flask app in a container.
I'm using Traefik as a reverse proxy in another container.

If I make the following request in Chrome by pasting the URL in, the GET request works:

```
https://api.my-app.new/api/admin/user?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0
```

However, if I attemtp to make the same GET request from a React app, an OPTIONS preflight request is made and it is failing with a 404.
I've traced through it as best I can in PyCharm and the problem seems to be in the following code in Flask's app.py:

```
def preprocess_request(self):
    bp = _request_ctx_stack.top.request.blueprint
```

Basically, the blueprint is not found.

What is actually getting sent is seen in this curl call:

```
curl 'https://api.my-app.new/api/admin/user?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0' \
     -X OPTIONS -H 'access-control-request-method: GET' -H 'origin: https://admin.my-app.new' \
     -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
     -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36' \
     -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://admin.my-app.new/' -H 'authority: api.my-app.new' \
     -H 'access-control-request-headers: authorization,content-type' --compressed
```

And if I print out the headers received by the Flask-app (in @app.before_request), I get the following:

```
[2018-01-25 04:31:48,438] INFO - X-Forwarded-Server: cb5d56692c6d
Referer: https://admin.my-app.new/
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Origin: https://admin.my-app.new
X-Real-Ip: 172.19.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
Host: api.my-app.new
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
X-Forwarded-Host: api.my-app.new
X-Forwarded-For: 172.19.0.1
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

[2018-01-25 04:31:48,440] INFO - Error 404:/api/admin/user?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0: 404 Not Found: The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. ("/app/app/routes.py:87")
```

Now, if I make the same request with the app running without the traefik reverse proxy, it works. The only thing that is different in the curl
request is that I'm using http, instead of https.

Here are the headers that Flask receives in this case:

```
[2018-01-24 21:43:43,199] INFO - Referer: https://admin.my-app.new/
Origin: https://admin.my-app.new
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Authority: api.my-app.new
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Host: api.my-app.new:8000
Accept: */*
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

[24/Jan/2018 21:43:43] "OPTIONS /api/admin/user?_end=10&_order=DESC&_sort=id&_start=0 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I figure that there is something wrong with the headers or something that is confusing Flask. I saw another post from 2014 that mentioned needing the SERVER_NAME, but that didn't help.

Finally, I had originally used NGinx as a reserve proxy and had gotten everything working. One of the the things
that was hard to get working with NGinx was redirects and OPTION requests. I did get it working after madly chasing down various blog 
posts, but as I look back on it as I right this, I notice a curious thing: I wound up writing script in nginx.conf
to automatically return 200 for all OPTIONS requests!

Any idea why the OPTION requests are failing?

Comment: [It's a bug](https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1662). Feel free to contribute into fixing it. Downgrading should help.

Comment: Thanks. I found the CherryPy issue yesterday evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As webKnjaZ notes: "It's a bug."

After digging in deeper, I discovered that the problem that Flask was getting different URL for the GET request than for the OPTIONS request, and that if CherryPy was removed the problem went away. That led me to this CherryPy issue which describes my situation exactly.

https://github.com/cherrypy/cherrypy/issues/1662

The author noted that the bug appeared when moving from CherryPy 11 to 12 (I was on 13.x) so I tried downgrading to 11.0.0 and that fixed it.

Comment: I'm working on the fix and will probably do some refactoring in Cheroot as well. I just need to decide on the best course of action there.

Comment: I'm subscribed to the bug, so will follow along. It seems like the old behavior was the correct one, though.